# Strange SDL getAttribute() behaviour

Tags: opengl, sdl-2, glew

I instructed SDL to use at least 8 bits for the stencil buffer:

```
if (SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_STENCIL_SIZE, 8) < 0)
{
    printf("couldn't set stencil size: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
}
```

That works because it gives no error.
But later in the code, I try to get the stencil size value:

```
int rc, i;
rc = SDL_GL_GetAttribute(SDL_GL_STENCIL_SIZE, &i);
printf("stencil buffer size: (returns %i):%i  sdl-error:%s\n", rc, i, SDL_GetError());
```

That returns -1, and outputs this:

```
stencil buffer size: (returns -1):0  sdl-error:OpenGL error: GL_INVALID_ENUM
```

If cleared any SDL error using `SDL_ClearError()`, so this must be the reason. But I have no idea why.

Maybe there might be a bigger error, since `glGetError()` returns `GL_INVALID_ENUM` right after GLEW initialization, the same error as SDL gives.

**Note:** Thanks @Nicol Bolas, I edited the wrong call.

**EDIT:**
I tried to change the context version, and the greatest version which works, is 3.1, glew generates no error, and sdl returns 8 as stencil size.
But why? I read the GLEW changelog, and it says, that my glew version (1.13.0) should be able to handle opengl 4: http://glew.sourceforge.net/

So, what's wrong?

Comment: `SDL_GL_GetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, &i)` That has nothing to do with the number of stencil bits. So I fail to see how this code gets the stencil size of the default framebuffer.

Answer (score 0):

Since the stencil stuff works now, I just cleared the error generated by GLEW by calling `glGetError()`. For those who are interested, here is paragraph concerning the error: (link:https://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library)

> GLEW has a problem with core contexts. It calls glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS)​, which causes GL_INVALID_ENUM on GL 3.2+ core context as soon as glewInit()​ is called. It also doesn't fetch the function pointers. The solution is for GLEW to use glGetStringi​ instead. The current version of GLEW is 1.10.0 but they still haven't corrected it. The only fix is to use glewExperimental​ for now.glewExperimental​ is a variable that is already defined by GLEW. You must set it to GL_TRUE before calling glewInit()​. You might still get GL_INVALID_ENUM (depending on the version of GLEW you use), but at least GLEW ignores glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS)​ and gets all function pointers.